# Firefox AdBlock Plus

Tags: firefox, adblock

I have Adblock Plus , Firefox Addon installed with my Firefox ver. 3.6.17. In this, I don't see any setting wherein I can selectively add site urls/domains as exceptions to the Adblock filter.

e.g. I would like to see ads shown by www.google.com

On a different Firefox of ver. 4.0, with this Adblock plus addon, I can see a setting in my status bar which I can click and enter domain exceptions for the adblock filter?

I checked in this Firefox settings, but could not find.

Any pointers.

Thank you.

Comment: May I recommend uBlock Origin instead of adblock: It uses significantly less memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just navigate to google, click the ABP-icon dropdown in the toolbar/addonbar and choose "Disable on google.com"

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Addons, find AdBlock Plus and click "options" and you should be able to add exceptions even with a filter subscription.

The format for exceptions is something like: "@@||google.com^$document"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the button added to your toolbar, there is an option to `Disable on (this current site)`.  This will add an exception for the site that you're currently browsing.

To add the button to your toolbar, right-click on the toolbar and select customize.  Then drag the adblock button to your desired location.